# Compiling/compressing into one js file

Tags: javascript, typescript, converters

I have a typescript project that compiles into javascript and runs in the browser. It utilizes the new-ish module system in javascript, and the files are in a hierarchy split into different folders. Are there any ways to convert my typescript files into just one javascript file (i would prefer not to use amd or system), or compress my converted javascript files into a single file? I cant just paste everything into a file as the code is split into modules, files and folders.

Comment: [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)? Also, I would not really call the JavaScript module system "new-ish", as ES6 is 4 years old.

Comment: Sounds like youre looking for a module bundler - webpack is a popular one: https://webpack.js.org/  - Given some entry point, it will create a dependency graph and bundle up all the modules you need.

Comment: Thanks guys, i had completely forgotten about webpack.

Answer (score 1):

outFile will concatenate the output.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "System"
      "outFile": "<file/location>",
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but then id have to use system

Comment: I see, sorry! I think the bundler is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I can just use the module bundler [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).